# Connect Mail.app on OS X 10.6 to Gmail using Exchange

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, gmail, exchange

I want to use the Exchange protocol to connect Mail.app to Gmail, mostly so I can use the "subscriptions" feature to prevent Mail.app from downloading all the Spam and All Mail messages that I'll never use from my fat client.

When I open Mail.app it asks for email and password, which I provide. Then it sets up the account as IMAP. I don't want IMAP, I want exchange. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible I'm afraid, as there is [no support](http://blog.aaronmarks.com/?p=42) for MAPI-extended (aka Exchange protocol) on OS X. Even MS's own product, Entourage doesn't support MAPI, instead using a combination of IMAP and OWA to access mail.

Just a note - Exchange support on the Iphone is done through ActiveSync, which is not used by Mail.app. Given this, I'm pretty sure Gmail doesn't even make mailboxes available using the Exchange protocol, so the discussion may be moot.

Comment: It's curious that iOS is so far ahead of Mac OS X when it comes to business.

Answer (score 2):

@imoatama I think you must have Googled something of the sort "os x exchange" and clicked the first link (I did just that, and got the link you referenced), resulting in an out of date answer.

os X Mail does indeed support exchange now, if you're running 10.6.xx (snow leopard). However, @imoatama is correct that gmail is not available in exchange protocol, so it is not possible to do what you are asking.

Comment: I read a few links. I gathered that OS X mail supports Exchange, but not via the MAPI-extended protocol. It uses MAPI-simple. And the exchange server has to be setup to accommodate the Mac client.